# How to refresh tableau extracts by using shell script

Tags: python, shell, unix, teradata, tableau-api

We have Tableau reports, which are currently pointing to live connection and using a custom sql query with start date and end date as parameters and Teradata as DB. As live is always slow process to retrieve the data, I wanted to write a shell script or python to run the Teradata queries based on schedule.
My Approach : Create control table and store the custom sql queries in it and run those queries in server and save the result in tde file and push it to tableau server.

Can anyone please help me with better solution or how to run Teradata queries via Unix or Phython and how to send the extracts to tableau server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not let Tableau Server refresh the extract? You can set up a schedule and it will do all the work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not allowed for me. And so im exploring the other options.